# Why my login session crossing to all logged in device in the same server

Tags: php, session, server

On my login script, if a user like User A login from anywhere the User B after login from any other device gets all session data of User A (User B's login page showed login as User A). I create a session token and save it database with a username. Also, create a user ID for each user too and save it on the database. I cannot understand how my session data passing another device. On the test, I create a page for the session data by `print_r($_SESSION);` Which also showed the same data on both devices. I cannot found any solution in my script to solve it. Does anyone can help me. Here is my script.

login.php

```
<form id="loginform" role="form" action="logprocess.php" method="POST">
<input id="login-username" type="text" name="user" value="" placeholder="username">
<input id="login-password" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="password" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>">
<input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" <?php if($value("remember") != ""){ echo "checked"; } ?>> Remember me
<input type="submit" value="Login" id="loginhere">
```

logprocess.php

```
include_once("session.php");
global $session;
if ($_SESSION['token']==$_POST['token']) {
   $login = $session->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], isset($_POST['remember']));
   header("Location:".$session->referrer);
}
```

session.php

```
require_once("database.php");
class Session
   {
   var $id;
   var $username;
   var $uid;
   var $logged_in;
   function Session(){
       $this->startSession();
       $this->time = time();
   }
   function startSession(){
       global $database;
       session_start();
       $this->logged_in = $this->checkLogin();
       if(!$this->logged_in){
           $database->addGuest($_SESSION['uid'], $this->time);
       } else{
           if($_SESSION['username'] != ''){
           $database->addUser($_SESSION['username'], $this->time);
       } else {return false;}
   }
   if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
       if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
           $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
       } else {
           $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
       }
   }
  $token = $_SESSION['token'];

  function checkLogin(){
      global $database;

      /* Check if user has been remembered */
      if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookid'])){
         $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['cookname'];
         $this->uid   = $_SESSION['uid']   = $_COOKIE['cookid'];
      }

     /* Username and userid have been set and not guest */
     if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['token']) && isset($_SESSION['uid']) &&
     $_SESSION['username'] != "guest"){ 
     /* Confirm that username and userid are valid */
     if($database->confirmUserID($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['uid']) != 0 && $database->confirmUserToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['username']) != 0){
        /* Variables are incorrect, user not logged in */
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['uid']);
        unset($_SESSION['token']);
        session_destroy();
        return false;
      }

      /* User is logged in, set class variables */
      $this->userinfo = $database->getUserInfo($_SESSION['username']);
      $this->id = $this->userinfo['id'];
      $this->username = $this->userinfo['username'];
      $this->uid = $this->userinfo['uid'];
      $this->email = $this->userinfo['email'];
      return true;
      } else { return false; }
   }

   function login($user, $pass, $remember){
      $result = $database->confirmUserPass($user, $pass);
      if($result == 1){
          return false;
      } 
      $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'] = $this->generateRandID(32);
      $database->updateUserField($user, "uid", $this->uid);
      $database->updateToken($user, $_SESSION['token']);
      if($remember){
         setcookie("cookname", $user, time()+60*60*24*3, "/");
         setcookie("cookid",   $this->uid,   time()+60*60*24*3, "/");
      }
   return true;
   }

$session = new Session;
}
```

anypage.php

```
include_once("session.php");
if($session->logged_in){
   /*Do anything*/
}
```

Comment: Please check the user tokens, they could be same in some cases

Comment: I didn't saw it before, yaa token is same too!!

Comment: tokens Must be different for all user sessions

Comment: I suggest using UUIDs for the tokens, mysql can generate these for you using a built-in function. But...are you trying to make it so that once a user has logged in on one device, they don't have to log in again on other devices? I wasn't sure what the aim of this was. Normally there is no need to store a special login token in the database. I mention it because that's not a secure thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Session Token Must be different for all of the user sessions, to identify each user and each device separately.

I suggest to use UUID for unique tokens.

UUID - A universally unique identifier is a 128-bit number used to identify information in computer systems.

Comment: if generate any random ID by any process for session its shows the same everywhere every device. I am confused what can I do.